# How to make Mutter default window manager

Tags: debian, window-manager, gnome2

I'm running Debian Squeeze and removed Metacity in favor of [Mutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutter_%28window_manager%29). How do I avoid having to run `mutter --replace` each time I start Xorg (GNOME)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press Alt + F2 and enter `gconf-editor`. Navigate the tree menu to desktop > gnome > session > required-components. Now, replace the `windowmanager` key with the window manager of your choice. Just replace gnome-wm (or metacity) with mutter.

Another possible solution:

You could add `mutter --replace` to **System** > **Preferences** > **Startup Applications** which opens **`gnome-session-properties`** program:

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: I'm actually having the same problem. And no, editing gconf didn't work.

Comment: You could add `mutter --replace` to System > Preferences > Startup Applications

Answer (score 1):

Under Debian, if you want to change the window manager for all users, you can run (as root):

```
update-alternatives --config x-window-manager
```

and select the window manager you want as the default.  However, this might only work if you're not using a desktop environment (e.g. GNOME or KDE).

If you're using GNOME, you can tell it which window manager you want by putting the following in `~/.gnomerc`:

```
export WINDOW_MANAGER=/usr/bin/mutter
```

Comment: That file doesn't exists in my home dir. Must I create it?

Comment: @tshepang yes, create it. This answer is is the correct method on Debian.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get metacity as window manager.